# Makefile "No such file or directory", object files not created

Tags: c++, makefile

Suppose I have the following folder layout:

```
my_dir
|-- Makefile
|->bin
|->include
   |-- entry.hpp
   |-- hashes.hpp
   |-- linear_map.hpp
   |-- robinhood_map.hpp
|->out
|->tests
   |-> test_speed.cpp
```

with the following dependencies:

```
               /--> robinhood_map.hpp \
test_speed.cpp                         ----> hashes.hpp, entries.hpp
               \--> linar_map.hpp     /
```

I wrote the following Makefile to compile my speed test:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11 
INC = -I/Users/aqho/Desktop/PersonalCodingProjects/HashTable/include

all: bin/test_speed

test:
    ./bin/test_speed

bin/test_speed: out/test_speed.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o bin/test_speed out/test_speed.o
    
out/test_speed.o: tests/test_speed.cpp 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c tests/test_speed.cpp
```

However, when I run `make all`, I get the following error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/test_speed.o'
```

I'm a little confused why this is happening. My understanding is that when `make all` gets called, then it will go to the rule for `bin/test_speed`, then it will look at the rule for `out/test_speed.o`. Then it will create the -o file and go back to the rule for `bin/test_speed`. However, the `test_speed.o` file isn't being created, which causes my rule for `bin/test_speed` to fail. Can somebody point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You aren't specifying `-o` on the rule that builds `out/test_speed.o`, so it will put the object file next to the source file.

Comment: Also remember that the default `%.o: %.cpp` rule expands to `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $@ $<`; there are quite a few differences from yours, and all except the `$(TARGET_ARCH)` are significant

Comment: @o11c I'm a little confused what you mean by specifying the `-o` on the rule that builds `out/test_speed.o`. I thought in that rule, I had to use `-c` to compile the `.cpp` file to an object file

Comment: Please refer to the [option descriptions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall%20Options) for the `GNU` compiler.  `-c` and `-o` perform two very different functions.

Comment: (and, you can and virtually always will use both at the same time when compiling into object files)

Comment: If you want an opinionated (arguably, all makefiles are) example of a Makefile that "does everything" (with a couple TODOs that a beginner probably won't run into), I have an [example project](https://github.com/o11c/makefile-demo)